# Can not read file in XCODE 4.2, worked in 4.0?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, encoding, nsstring

I have upgraded from XCODE 4 to 4.2 and now i have problems.

The following code worked pre 4.2 to read the file in "filePath":

```
// Fill myString with questions from the .txt file and then read .txt file
NSString *filePath = whatFile; 
NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

// Load array
NSArray* myArray = [myString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\r"];
NSLog (@"\n \n Number of elements in myArray = %i", [myArray count]);
```

With 4.2 the "initWithContentsOfFile" in the following code line is deprecated:

```
NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

...and should be replaced with the below according to the manual:

```
NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&err];
```

and i can not get this to read the records in the same file by replacing the code line. BTW, i have defined the &err.

When i NSLog myString i get (null).

I am getting a bit desperate to solve this and would very much appreciate any help.

Cheers

Comment: And what does the error object tell you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSLog` the `err` variable if there is an error.  Also `NSLog` `filePath`.

Perhaps the encoding is not UTF-8, are you sure about the encoding?

The best non-UTF-8 encoding bet is `NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding` which supports 8-bit characters.

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
    NSError* error = nil;
    NSStringEncoding encoding;
    NSString *fileContent = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath usedEncoding:&encoding error:&error];
```

If that does not works, try in your code : `NSASCIIStringEncoding`

Answer (score 0):

The file probably doesn't contain a UTF8 encoded string. See apple's documentation, which has an example of reading a file where you do not know the encoding: [Reading data with an unknown encoding](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/readingFiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003459-SW4)

You need to use the `[string|init]WithContentsOfFile:usedEncoding:error` method, and if that fails there are a few more things you can try before finally presenting an error message to the user (for example, try reading it as an `NSAttributedString`).

For example, you could do this:

```
// Fill myString with questions from the .txt file and then read .txt file
NSString *filePath = whatFile; 
NSStringEncoding encoding;
NSError *error;
NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath usedEncoding:&encoding error:&error];

if (!myString) {
  myString = [[NSString alloc] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error]
}

if (!myString) {
  myString = [[NSString alloc] encoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding error:&error]
}

if (!myString) {
  NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
  return;
}


// Load array
NSArray* myArray = [myString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\r"];
NSLog (@"\n \n Number of elements in myArray = %i", [myArray count]);
```